# Pushing array into array inside of array

Tags: php, array-push

I'm trying to insert an array or (if there is one already declared) add element to it.

> Print_r output of $data array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7727368
            [1] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7727284
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 7543419783
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7787473
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 7771723347
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 8458457
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

> PHP Code:

```
  $idaukcji = $_POST['idaukcji'];
  $modid = $_POST['modid'];
  foreach($data as $item){
    foreach($item[1] as $subitem){
      if($subitem[0]==$idaukcji){
        if(array_key_exists('1',$subitem)){
          array_push($subitem[1],$modid);
        }
        else{
          array_push($subitem, array($modid));
        }
      }
      $tobase = base64_encode(serialize($item[1]));
      $sql="UPDATE data SET allegroaucnum='$tobase' WHERE wfnum = '$item[0]'";
      mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    }
  }
```

The script should check if there is an existing array on index [1] of most deeply nested array if it is declared then it should add `$modid` to that array, If not then create the array with `$modid` as an element.

Actual code gives what we can see above (in print_r) but if I add

```
echo $subitem[1][0];
```

after (inside else)

```
array_push($subitem, array($modid));
```

It does return $modid value which somehow is not shown in print_r

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: To modify inner arrays set them as references:  `foreach($data as &$item){
    foreach($item[1] as &$subitem){`

Comment: Array push can adds values to an existing array.
If you want to assign values to a specific array index, you need to do it explicitly by using array[index][whatever] = value

Comment: @splash58 thanks! that helped !

Answer (score 1):

try this function:

```
function flat_array($array, &$result) 
{
    if(!is_array($array)) {
        return $array;
    }
    foreach ($array as $key => $item) {
        if(is_array($item)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
            flat_array($item,  $result);
        } else {
            $result[] =  $item;
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

execution code

```
flat_array($array, $result);
$result = array_unique($result); // if you want to make sure thar each value is unique
```